# Xcode crashing with selection failed. window:<IDEWorkspaceWindow: 0x7fe212057430> currentlySelectedTabbedWindow:<IDEWorkspaceWindow: 0x7fe213cb5310>

Tags: xcode10.1

Code crashing with below stack traces:

It will not allowed to open project file which was already opened and minimised.

Process:               Xcode [644]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode_10.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               10.1 (14460.46)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks_Fall2018-14460046000000000~5 (10B61)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       828917606
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [644]
User ID:               869373484

Date/Time:             2020-03-27 13:48:49.845 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.3 (19D76)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        FD8C88EB-3C2B-91CF-2711-0652F5A776A1

Time Awake Since Boot: 85 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 10B61
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks_Fall2018/IDEFrameworks-14460.46/IDEKit/Workspace/IDEWorkspaceDocument.m:3335
Details:  selection failed. window: currentlySelectedTabbedWindow:
Object:   
Method:   -_restoreSelectedTabsByIdentifierFromStateSaving:
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
Hints:

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
window == [window currentlySelectedTabbedWindow]

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff67ae67fa __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff67ba3bc1 pthread_kill + 432
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff67a6da1c abort + 120
3   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d960793 +[IDEAssertionHandler _handleAssertionWithLogString:assertionSignature:assertionReason:extraBacktrace:] + 1324
4   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d960dbf -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] + 1256
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010bd1018a _DVTAssertionHandler + 374
6   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010bd10463 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler + 374
7   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d889b7a -[IDEWorkspaceDocument _restoreSelectedTabsByIdentifierFromStateSaving:] + 1886
8   com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d88594b -[IDEWorkspaceDocument revertStateWithDictionary:] + 267
9   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010bba380b -[DVTStateToken _pullStateFromDictionary:] + 357
10  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010bba3bf7 -[DVTStateToken pullStateFromRepository] + 179
11  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d87e2ac -[IDEWorkspaceDocument _readFromURL:ofType:simpleFilesFocused:error:] + 921
12  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010d87e88c -[IDEWorkspaceDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] + 134
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d800db9 -[NSDocument _initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 172
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d800ca2 -[NSDocument initWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 231
15  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010dc78b3e -[IDEDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:ofType:error:] + 2064
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2da6a91c __97-[NSDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 91
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2da6a8b6 -[NSDocumentController makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:] + 160
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d86e8e2 __80-[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]_block_invoke + 839
19  com.apple.dt.IDEKit             0x000000010dc7ed59 __145-[IDEDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke + 226
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2da69ab8 __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke_4 + 31
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2da69e0e __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke_2.872 + 177
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2da69cf7 __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke.871 + 153
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2da69c0b __144-[NSDocumentController _coordinateReadingAndGetAlternateContentsForOpeningDocumentAtURL:resolvingSymlinks:thenContinueOnMainThreadWithAccessor:]_block_invoke.869 + 243
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2da762bf ___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlockInModes_block_invoke + 25
25  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff302fb7ab __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff302fb6ed __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 379
27  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff302fa731 __CFRunLoopRun + 1257
28  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff302f9bd3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 499
29  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2ee4f65d RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
30  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2ee4f2a9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 356
31  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff2ee4f127 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d4bfba4 _DPSNextEvent + 990
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d4be380 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1352
34  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010c376584 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 385
35  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d4b009e -[NSApplication run] + 658
36  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff2d482465 NSApplicationMain + 777
37  com.apple.dt.Xcode              0x000000010ba7e82e main + 574
38  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6799f7fd start + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by following  steps  below :

```
1> Delete DerivedData
2> updates pods if your project have
3> Delete xcUserData from .xcworkspace and .xcproject file .
```

Solution found on below article please check this for more information.
[https://technuisance.com/xcode/xcode-crash-assertion-failure.html][1]